# How to do an event for template element?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I there any chance in WPF to do a event for control in template not creating a UserControl or so on?
For example: created window template has custom "Close(X)" button. It has the same operation for every windows. It is any chance to make it working? Give Click event which will close the window?

I mean to use it like this:

```
<Window style="{StaticResource MyWindowTemplate}">...</Window>
```

And doesnt create custom class of Window because I want to have opportunity to use it to every classes of Windows.

So there is any chance to do it like this? Or any similar or better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think `Template` can achieve a behavior. They are for look and feel but not behavior. For behaviors we have attached properties and behaviors which when attached to their valid target dependency objects to behave all the same.

e.g. in your case the close button on the top right corner is a difficult one but any button on the window close a target UI i.e. Window itself when specified with some attached behavior.

```
 <Window x:Class="..."
         ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentControl ... />
        <Buton Width="100"
               Content="Close"
               local:CloseBehavior.IsCloseButton="True" />
   </Grid>
 </Window>
```

So in the example above any button that is configured with an attached behavior `local:CloseBehavior.IsCloseButton="True"` makes that button click to close its ancestor window.

**EDIT:**

`CloseBehavior.IsCloseButton` is something like given below. So in the code below when we set `IsCloseButton` attached property as `true` against any button on any window, using visual and logical traversal the attached behavior searches the ancestor window and then closes it when clicked.

```
public static class CloseBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCloseButtonProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsCloseButton",
            typeof (bool),
            typeof (CloseBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(
               false,
               OnIsCloseButtonPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnIsCloseButtonPropertyChanged
        (DependencyObject depObj,
         DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var buttonBase = depObj as ButtonBase;
        if (buttonBase != null && (bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            buttonBase.Click
                += (o, args) =>
                    {
                        var window
                            = GetVisualLogicalParent(
                                  buttonBase,
                                  typeof(Window)) as Window;

                        if (window != null)
                        {
                            window.Close();
                        }
                    };
        }
    }

    public static bool GetIsCloseButton(DependencyObject depObj)
    {
        return (bool)depObj.GetValue(IsCloseButtonProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsCloseButton(
        DependencyObject depObj,
        bool value)
    {
        depObj.SetValue(IsCloseButtonProperty, value);
    }

    public static DependencyObject GetVisualLogicalParent(
       DependencyObject depObj,
       Type type)
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(depObj);
            if (parent == null)
            {
                parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(depObj);
            }
            if (parent != null)
            {
                if (type.IsInstanceOfType(parent))
                {
                    return parent;
                }
                else
                {
                    return GetVisualLogicalParent(parent, type);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. And how can I code this behaviour? Can you add also code for this behaviour? I hope it shouldn't be coded in every windows...

Comment: Plz see my code above. You wont have to code this behavior seperately for each window or button. Using this you can also update the `OnIsCloseButtonPropertyChanged()` method to apply tooltips, styles, templates, more behaviors on the close button as you want.

Comment: Maybe I was too quickly. I have error "The attachable property 'IsCloseButton' was not found in type 'CloseBehavior'"

Comment: Works perfectly in my case. What is your local: namespace referring to?

Comment: I have <ResourceDictionary .... xmlns:local="WpfApplication">...</...> where is a class of CloseBehavior.

Comment: No! `CloseBehavior` is a static class. It doesnt have to be instantiated in your resources. The way attached properties work is via static declarations. Hence I asked if the `local` namespace has the class correctly defined (the way I explained above) then referring it via the namespace should work.

Comment: Ok that was my fault. Thank ones again :)